# How to run a sub in a `Create` function and how to make a mock/stub/fake for a chart `Series`?

Tags: excel, vba, rubberduck

## Preface

*About 10 years ago I started refactoring and improving the `ChartSeries` class of John Walkenbach. Unfortunately it seems that the original it is not available any more online.*

*Following the [Rubberduck Blog](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/) for quite some time now I try to improve my VBA skills. But in the past I only have written -- I guess the experts would call it -- "script-like god-procedures" (because of not knowing better). So I am pretty new to classes and especially interfaces and factories.*

## Actual Questions

I try to refactor the whole class by dividing it into multiple classes also using interfaces and than also adding unit tests. For just **reading** the parts of a formula it would be sufficient to get the `Series.Formula` and then do all the processing. So it would be nice to call the `Run` sub in the `Create` function. But everything I tried so far to do so failed. Thus, I currently running `Run` in all `Get` properties etc. (and test, if the formula changed and exit `Run` than. Is this possible and when yes, how?

Second, to add unit tests -- of course using [rubberduck](/questions/tagged/rubberduck) for them -- I currently rely on **real** `Charts`/`ChartObjects`. How do I create a stub/mock/fake for a `Series`? (Sorry, I don't know the correct term.)

And here a simplified version of the code.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

### normal module

```vb
'@Folder("ChartSeries")

Option Explicit

Public Sub ExampleUsage()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    Dim crt As ChartObject
    Set crt = wks.ChartObjects(1)
    
    Dim srs As Series
    Set srs = crt.Chart.SeriesCollection(3)
    
    Dim MySeries As IChartSeries
    Set MySeries = ChartSeries.Create(srs)
    With MySeries
        Debug.Print .XValues.FormulaPart
    End With
End Sub
```

### IChartSeries.cls

```vb
'@Folder("ChartSeries")
'@Interface

Option Explicit

Public Function IsSeriesAccessible() As Boolean
End Function

Public Property Get FullFormula() As String
End Property

Public Property Get XValues() As ISeriesPart
End Property

'more properties ...
```

### ChartSeries.cls

```vb
'@PredeclaredId
'@Exposed
'@Folder("ChartSeries")

Option Explicit
Implements IChartSeries

Private Type TChartSeries
   Series As Series
   FullSeriesFormula As String
   OldFullSeriesFormula As String
   IsSeriesAccessible As Boolean
   SeriesParts(eElement.[_First] To eElement.[_Last]) As ISeriesPart
End Type
Private This As TChartSeries

Public Function Create(ByVal Value As Series) As IChartSeries
'NOTE: I would like to run the 'Run' sub somewhere here (if possible)
   With New ChartSeries
      .Series = Value
      Set Create = .Self
   End With
End Function

Public Property Get Self() As IChartSeries
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Friend Property Let Series(ByVal Value As Series)
   Set This.Series = Value
End Property

Private Function IChartSeries_IsSeriesAccessible() As Boolean
   Call Run
   IChartSeries_IsSeriesAccessible = This.IsSeriesAccessible
End Function

Private Property Get IChartSeries_FullFormula() As String
   Call Run
   IChartSeries_FullFormula = This.FullSeriesFormula
End Property

Private Property Get IChartSeries_XValues() As ISeriesPart
   Call Run
   Set IChartSeries_XValues = This.SeriesParts(eElement.eXValues)
End Property

'more properties ...

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   With This
      Dim Element As eElement
      For Element = eElement.[_First] To eElement.[_Last]
         Set .SeriesParts(Element) = New SeriesPart
      Next
   End With
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
   With This
      Dim Element As LongPtr
      For Element = eElement.[_First] To eElement.[_Last]
         Set .SeriesParts(Element) = Nothing
      Next
   End With
End Sub

Private Sub Run()

   If Not GetFullSeriesFormula Then Exit Sub
   If Not HasFormulaChanged Then Exit Sub
   Call GetSeriesFormulaParts

End Sub

'(simplified version)
Private Function GetFullSeriesFormula() As Boolean

   GetFullSeriesFormula = False

   With This
'---
'dummy to make it work
.FullSeriesFormula = _
"=SERIES(Tabelle1!$B$2,Tabelle1!$A$3:$A$5,Tabelle1!$B$3:$B$5,1)"
'---
      .OldFullSeriesFormula = .FullSeriesFormula
      .FullSeriesFormula = .Series.Formula
   End With
   
   GetFullSeriesFormula = True

End Function

Private Function HasFormulaChanged() As Boolean
   With This
      HasFormulaChanged = (.OldFullSeriesFormula <> .FullSeriesFormula)
   End With
End Function

Private Sub GetSeriesFormulaParts()
   
   Dim MySeries As ISeriesFormulaParts
   '(simplified version without check for Bubble Chart)
   Set MySeries = SeriesFormulaParts.Create( _
         This.FullSeriesFormula, _
         False _
   )
   
   With MySeries
      Dim Element As eElement
      For Element = eElement.[_First] To eElement.[_Last] - 1
         This.SeriesParts(Element).FormulaPart = _
               .PartSeriesFormula(Element)
      Next
'---
'dummy which normally would be retrieved
'by 'MySeries.PartSeriesFormula(eElement.eXValues)'
This.SeriesParts(eElement.eXValues).FormulaPart = _
"Tabelle1!$A$3:$A$5"
'---
   End With
   
   Set MySeries = Nothing

End Sub

'more subs and functions ...
```

### ISeriesPart.cls

```vb
'@Folder("ChartSeries")
'@Interface

Option Explicit

Public Enum eEntryType
   eNotSet = -1
   [_First] = 0
   eInaccessible = eEntryType.[_First]
   eEmpty
   eInteger
   eString
   eArray
   eRange
   [_Last] = eEntryType.eRange
End Enum

Public Property Get FormulaPart() As String
End Property

Public Property Let FormulaPart(ByVal Value As String)
End Property

Public Property Get EntryType() As eEntryType
End Property

Public Property Get Range() As Range
End Property

'more properties ...
```

### SeriesPart.cls

```vb
'@PredeclaredId
'@Folder("ChartSeries")
'@ModuleDescription("A class to handle each part of the 'Series' string.")

Option Explicit

Implements ISeriesPart

Private Type TSeriesPart
   FormulaPart As String
   EntryType As eEntryType
   Range As Range
   RangeString As String
   RangeSheet As String
   RangeBook As String
   RangePath As String
End Type
Private This As TSeriesPart

Private Property Get ISeriesPart_FormulaPart() As String
   ISeriesPart_FormulaPart = This.FormulaPart
End Property

Private Property Let ISeriesPart_FormulaPart(ByVal Value As String)
   This.FormulaPart = Value
   Call Run
End Property

Private Property Get ISeriesPart_EntryType() As eEntryType
   ISeriesPart_EntryType = This.EntryType
End Property

Private Property Get ISeriesPart_Range() As Range
   With This
      If .EntryType = eEntryType.eRange Then
         Set ISeriesPart_Range = .Range
      Else
'         Call RaiseError
      End If
   End With
End Property

Private Property Set ISeriesPart_Range(ByVal Value As Range)
   Set This.Range = Value
End Property

'more properties ...

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   This.EntryType = eEntryType.eNotSet
End Sub

Private Sub Run()
   '- set 'EntryType'
   '- If it is a range then find the range parts ...
End Sub

'a lot more subs and functions ...
```

### ISeriesParts.cls

```vb
'@Folder("ChartSeries")
'@Interface

Option Explicit

Public Enum eElement
   [_First] = 1
   eName = eElement.[_First]
   eXValues
   eYValues
   ePlotOrder
   eBubbleSizes
   [_Last] = eElement.eBubbleSizes
End Enum

'@Description("fill me")
Public Property Get PartSeriesFormula(ByVal Element As eElement) As String
End Property
```

### SeriesFormulaParts.cls

```vb
'@PredeclaredId
'@Exposed
'@Folder("ChartSeries")

Option Explicit

Implements ISeriesFormulaParts

Private Type TSeriesFormulaParts
   FullSeriesFormula As String
   IsSeriesInBubbleChart As Boolean
   WasRunCalled As Boolean
   
   SeriesFormula As String

   RemainingFormulaPart(eElement.[_First] To eElement.[_Last]) As String
   PartSeriesFormula(eElement.[_First] To eElement.[_Last]) As String
End Type
Private This As TSeriesFormulaParts

Public Function Create( _
   ByVal FullSeriesFormula As String, _
   ByVal IsSeriesInBubbleChart As Boolean _
      ) As ISeriesFormulaParts
'NOTE: I would like to run the 'Run' sub somewhere here (if possible)
   With New SeriesFormulaParts
      .FullSeriesFormula = FullSeriesFormula
      .IsSeriesInBubbleChart = IsSeriesInBubbleChart
      Set Create = .Self
   End With
End Function

Public Property Get Self() As ISeriesFormulaParts
    Set Self = Me
End Property

'@Description("Set the full series formula ('ChartSeries')")
Public Property Let FullSeriesFormula(ByVal Value As String)
   This.FullSeriesFormula = Value
End Property

Public Property Let IsSeriesInBubbleChart(ByVal Value As Boolean)
   This.IsSeriesInBubbleChart = Value
End Property

Private Property Get ISeriesFormulaParts_PartSeriesFormula(ByVal Element As eElement) As String
'NOTE: Instead of running 'Run' here, it would be better to run it in 'Create'
   Call Run
   ISeriesFormulaParts_PartSeriesFormula = This.PartSeriesFormula(Element)
End Property

'(replaced with a dummy)
Private Sub Run()

   If This.WasRunCalled Then Exit Sub
   'extract stuff from
   This.WasRunCalled = True
   
End Sub

'a lot more subs and functions ...
```

Comment: Good stuff! I started a review, but then hit `'more properties ...`, and it mades me wonder how many there are, what they are, and how "simplified" the code is. Consider an [edit] to include the whole actual thing, or to link to the full code on GitHub/PasteBin (note: only the code that's directly included in the post is reviewable).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, the master himself, that is awesome :) As requested, I have created a GitHub repository and edited the question accordingly. I'll be happy to receive **any** advice on how to improve the code. When you are in the mood, besides answering this question(s), you could file issues on GitHub as you like and I'll try my best to solve them. Hope, there is much to learn.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, awesome that you already answered before I could upload the full code ;) I quickly read the answer to the first question and I guess that I have got the point, although not understanding everything. Later this evening I'll read again and then translating stuff that I didn't understand. If it is ok for you, I'll ping you again when something is unclear. My plan was to post the full code on Code Review when I have **finished** refactoring which will most likely will take some more time. When I have more questions, I'll ask them here again.

Comment: Ping me anytime, *my* goal is to make sure what I write makes sense and is understandable! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can already!

> ```
> Public Function Create(ByVal Value As Series) As IChartSeries
>    With New ChartSeries <~ With block variable has access to members of the ChartSeries class
>       .Series = Value
>       Set Create = .Self
>    End With
> End Function
> ```

...only, like the `.Series` and `.Self` properties, it has to be a `Public` member of the `ChartSeries` interface/class (the line is blurry in VBA, since every class has a default interface / is also an interface).

#### Idiomatic Object Assignment

A note about this property:

> ```
> Friend Property Let Series(ByVal Value As Series)
>    Set This.Series = Value
> End Property
> ```

Using a `Property Let` member to `Set` an object reference will work - but it isn't idiomatic VBA code anymore, as you can see in the `.Create` function:

> ```
>       .Series = Value
> ```

If we read this line without knowing about the nature of the property, this looks like any other value assignment. Only problem is, we're not assigning a *value*, but a *reference* - and reference assignments in VBA are normally made using a `Set` keyword. If we change the `Let` for a `Set` in the `Series` property definition, we would have to do this:

```
      Set .Series = Value
```

And that would look much more readily like the reference assignment it is! Without it, there appears to be implicit let-coercion happening, and that makes it ambiguous code: VBA requires a `Set` keyword for reference assignments, because any given object *can* have a paraterless default property (e.g. how `foo = Range("A1")` implicitly assigns `foo` to the `Value` of the `Range`).

---

#### Caching & Responsibilities

Now, back to the `Run` method - if it's made `Public` on the `ChartSeries` class, but not exposed on the implemented `IChartSeries` interface, then it's a member that can only be invoked from 1) the `ChartSeries` default instance, or 2) any object variable that has a `ChartSeries` declared type. And since our "client code" is working off `IChartSeries`, we can guard against 1 and shrug off 2.

Note that the `Call` keyword is superfluous, and the `Run` method is really just pulling metadata from the encapsulated `Series` object, and caching it at instance level - I'd give it a name that sounds more like "refresh cached properties" than "run something".

Your hunch is a good one: `Property Get` should be a simple return function, without any side-effects. Invoking a method that scans an object and resets instance state in a `Property Get` accessor makes it side-effecting, which is a design smell - in theory.

If `Run` is invoked immediately after creation before the `Create` function returns the instance, then this `Run` method boils down to "parse the series and cache some metadata I'll reuse later", and there's nothing wrong with that: invoke it from `Create`, and remove it from the `Property Get` accessors.

The result is an object whose state is read-only and more robustly defined; the counterpart of that is that you now have an object whose state might be out of sync with the actual Excel `Series` object on the worksheet: if code (or the user) tweaks the `Series` object after the `IChartSeries` is initialized, the object and its state is stale.

One solution is to go out of your way to identify when a series is stale and make sure you keep the cache up-to-date.

Another solution would be to remove the problem altogether by no longer caching the state - that would mean one of two things:

1. Generating the object graph once on creation, effectively moving the caching responsibility to the caller: calling code gets a read-only "snapshot" to work with.
2. Generating a new object graph out of the series metadata, every time the calling code needs it: effectively, it moves the caching responsibility to the caller, which isn't a bad idea at all.

Making things read-only removes a lot of complexity! I'd go with the first option.

---

Overall, the code appears nice & clean (although it's unclear how much was scrubbed for this post) and you appear to have understood the *factory method* pattern leveraging the default instance and exposing a façade interface - kudos! The naming is overall pretty good (although "Run" sticks out IMO), and the objects look like they each have a clear, defined purpose. Good job!

---

#### Unit Testing

> *I currently rely on real Charts/ChartObjects. How do I create a stub/mock/fake for a Series? (Sorry, I don't know the correct term.)*

Currently, you can't. When [if/when this PR gets merged](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/pull/4681), you'll be able to *mock* Excel's interfaces (and much, much more) and write tests against your classes that inject a mock `Excel.Series` object that you can configure for your tests' purposes... but until then, this is where the wall is.

In the mean time, the best you can do is wrap it with your own interface, and *stub* it. In other words, wherever there's a seam between your code and Excel's object model, we slip an interface between the two: instead of taking in a `Excel.Series` object, you'd be taking in some `ISeriesWrapper`, and then the real code would be using an `ExcelSeriesWrapper` that works off an `Excel.Series`, and the test code might be using a `StubSeriesWrapper` whose properties return either hard-coded values, or values configured by tests: the code that works at the seam between the `Excel` library and your project, can't be tested - and we woulnd't want to anyway, because then we'd be testing Excel, not our own code.

You can see this in action in the example code for the next upcoming RD News article [here](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/examples/tree/master/SecureADODB); that article will discuss exactly this, using ADODB connections. The principle is the same: none of the 94 unit tests in that project ever open any actual connection, and yet with dependency injection and wrapper interfaces we're able to test every single bit of functionality, from opening a database connection to committing a transaction... without ever hitting an actual database.

Comment: That was simple, just making `Run` public was the solution I was searching for days! (It seems that in principle I have understood what you are always writing about, but when I try to apply it myself I stumble upon this small little details ...) Regarding the "Idiomatic Object Assignment": I am pretty sure while searching for above solution I had found this too, but then reverted to much when one of my tries to find above solution didn't work. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Regarding "Caching & Responsibilities": The current use case for all this is that I often get Excel files where the creators opinion is: "If data are not shown in charts, the data don't exist." And now the big task is to find out **where** the data in the charts are coming from and to check if the other information given in the chart are in sync with the Series. So I have another module where I grab all Charts in an Excel file and create a Table on a new sheet showing me all relevant information about that Chart(Object); including the data sources of the Series for what I use the above classes

Comment: So you got the point 100%. In my current use case of the above class(es) I only want to receive a snapshot of the current state of all the Series in the Charts and I have to manually update this to be sure that nothing is out of sync.

Comment: Currently I don't think that adding *write* features is worth the work (except of course for learning more stuff on how one *should* program in VBA). I think so because once you have the current parts of the formula you could create the new string for the part to change in whatever way and then simply concatenate the parts separating them with commata, surround it with `=SERIES(` and `)` and then set the `Series.Formula` to that new string.

Comment: Back to the track: What I didn't understand is the stuff starting with "One solution ..." up to "I'd go with the first option." Could you elaborate more on this, please? Especially the reference of this last sentence is unclear. I see "One solution" and "Another solution"; the latter having two subitems 1. and 2. Is the "first option" you are referring to "Solution one" or item 2 of the "other solution"?

Comment: Regarding "Unit Testing": Ok, I guess mean with the "Wrapper" stuff that I'll go for something similar you have written about in "There is no worksheet", right? But currently I don't have an idea how to do this for the `Series`. But I'll wait for the new RD News article and hope to understand it then. If not, I'll ask a follow-up question here on SO. So for now the "bad" news is, that I cannot create tests for the `ChartSeries` class yet. But the good news is, that I should be able to create them for the sub-classes, because they only need strings (and maybe booleans).

Comment: Ah, that part is weirdly worded indeed. I just meant that I'd go with 1 instead of 2 - that is, the immutable object graph (whereas 2 probably involves checks at every member call). The wrapper stuff: yeah that'd be it, sticking an interface between two systems decouples them, and formalizes how the other system is used (assuming all calls to that system go through the new interface). Cheers, and good job!

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Please note that I rolled the question back and will remove the GitHub repo, because it hadn't influenced the answer. Many thanks again for your help!!